# can we use React Native in an native Android project?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I currently have a native Kotlin Android project. Is it possible to use React Native inside of it?
I also have a native iOS project written in swift. WOuld React Native work there to?

If so, can you show me how to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. It is called bridging in react native.

You can follow this guide to integrate react native into your existing native application
https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps